# Stall all memory accesses of an application

Tags: performance, assembly, memory, x86-64, amd-processor

I want to analyze the effect of using slower memories on applications and need a mean to add delay for all memory accesses. Until now I investigated Intel PIN and other software but they seem to be overkill for what I need. Is there any tool to do so?

Is adding NOP operations in the binary code of the application right before each LOAD/STORE a feasible way?

Comment: I think you can lower the memory clock in the BIOS and turn off caching. What platform are you programming for?

Comment: x86_64, normal computers

Comment: Which CPU model? Which chipset?  There is likely no general way to do what you want, but individual CPUs and chipsets might have methods.

Comment: You might also want to check out cachegrind, a tool that simulates caching behaviour.

Comment: We have Intel 2630v4, AMD Opteron 6272, and Intel Xeon E5-2620 CPUs.

Comment: Can you set the memory clock in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes, I will try this. It is not optimal as it requires server restart and slowdowns all other applications, but it seems the fastest and most accurate solution.

Comment: You can probably also disable HW prefetch, which will make certain kinds of memory access a *lot* slower.  (e.g. looping through an array).  On Intel CPUs, there are some MSRs you can write to that will control this so you can do it temporarily without rebooting.  It will be a lot different than performance of a CPU behaving normally (full cache + HW prefetch) with slower memory, though.

Comment: And no, adding NOPs isn't going to be feasible or useful.  Most programs aren't bottlenecked on front-end bandwidth, so superscalar / out-of-order CPUs will chew through the NOPs pretty quickly.  They will take up space in the ROB, reducing how far ahead out-of-order execution can see, reducing the ability to hide L1 and L2 cache misses in some code, but mostly you wouldn't be affecting memory specifically; you'd be more likely to hurt CPU-bound code that gets lots of cache hits.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to run your application under an x86 simulator such as [MARSSx86](http://www.marss86.org/~marss86/index.php/Home) or [Sniper](http://snipersim.org/w/The_Sniper_Multi-Core_Simulator). Using these simulators you can smoothly vary the modeled memory latency or any other parameters of the system<sup>1</sup> and see how your application performance varies. This is a common approach in academia (often a generic machine will be modeled, rather than x86, which gives you access to more simulator implementations).

The primary disadvantage of using a simulator is that even good simulators are not completely accurate, and how accurate they are depends on the code in question. Certain types of variance from actual performance aren't particularly problematic when answering the question "how does performance vary with latency", but a simulator that doesn't model the memory access path well might produce a answer that is far from reality.

If you really can't use simulation, you could use any binary re-writing tool like PIN to instrument the memory access locations. `nop` would be a bad choice because it executes very quickly because you cannot add a dependency between the memory load result and the nop instruction. This latter issue means it only adds additional "work" at the location of each load, but that the work is independent of the load itself, so doesn't simulate increased memory latency.

A better approach would be to follow each load with a long latency operation that uses the result of the load as input and output (but doesn't modify it). Maybe something like `imul reg, reg, 1` if `reg` received the result of the load (but this only adds 3 cycles, so you might hunt for longer latency instructions if you want to add a lot of latency).

---

<sup>1</sup> At least within the set of things modeled by the simulator.

Comment: `push reg` / `pop reg` (not safe in code using the red zone) or store/reload to a per-thread static location would be more latency, but then you're introducing extra uops for the store load/store ports and more activity in the store buffer.  Depending what you're trying to learn, might be ok.

Comment: There are proposals for performance models of the load latency that can be implemented using only hardware performance counters available in modern Intel and AMD processors. They can and have been used to emulate in software slower load latencies. Compared to simulators, these techniques essentially have zero performance overhead (because they simply don't do any simulation). They are also more accurate with respect to real hardware and the emulation error can be measured on real hardware. The problem is that no one has come up yet with such a model...

Comment: ... for the store latency (there are a couple of proposals, but they they don't really work). So currently if one needs to emulate slower store latencies, the only way is to use a simulator like you suggested. Typically, real programs are much more impacted by the load latency than the store latency. But there are existing and emerging programs where the store latency does have a significant impact. I don't agree with your second suggestion though because I think the errors will be just too high.

Comment: @HadiBrais - I more or less ignored store latency entirely, because it's not even clear what you'd want here. Do you want to add time before the store appears in the store buffer? That seems weird, but it doable with instrumentation. Do you want to add time to the RFO request for the cache line when the store is close to being ready to leave the cache line? That seems more like what you'd want, but I don't see any way to implement it w/o hardware support.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "There are proposals for performance models of the load latency"? Do you mean something like recording performance counter data to characterize the application, and then applying some model to adjust the latency after the fact based on the collected data? I have considered something like that in the past. It seems very hard to make it work accurately in some scenarios. For example, I think there are scenarios that result in the same counter values but that have very different behaviors when latencies increase. I would like to hear more!

Comment: _I don't agree with your second suggestion though because I think the errors will be just too high._ - it depends, at least if your application is very heavily bound my memory access, some additional uops shouldn't hurt too much (but the problem is you might add way too many if you target _every_ memory access), but yeah the approach has a lot of problems.

Comment: Sure dude. My (current) favorite model on Intel is [this](http://www.jahrhundert.net/papers/middleware2015.pdf) and on AMD check [this](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc14/atc14-paper-su.pdf) out. An example of a failed attempt at emulating write latency is [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Soramichi_Akiyama/publication/317618191_Towards_Write-back_Aware_Software_Emulator_for_Non-Volatile_Memory/links/5943d9c90f7e9b6910ee22f9/Towards-Write-back-Aware-Software-Emulator-for-Non-Volatile-Memory.pdf) (no disrespect to the authors though, I appreciate their effort).

Comment: There are other models that are theoretically more accurate, but I'm not sure whether they can be implemented on real processor while preserving their theoretical accuracy. If you need more references, do let me know.

Comment: Yes the question is ambiguous (which discouraged me from posting an answer). Is the OP referring to the main memory latency from the perspective of the memory controller? Is the OP interested in asymmetric load and store latencies? How much modelling accuracy does the OP require? What is the target architecture? Does it have to be configurable (which rules out emulation on real hardware)? Note that the two simulators you suggested support a single latency parameter for all levels of the memory hierarchy (asymmetric latencies are not supported).